# Issue with my powershell script aimed to kick off a jenkins job

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, powershell-2.0

```
$UserName = "user"
$Password = "password"
$API_URL = "https://jenkinsservername"
$JobName = "firstjob"
$JobToken = "generatedtoken"
$header = @{}
$header.Add('Authorization', 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$(${UserName}):$(${Password})")))
$Params = @{uri = "${API_URL}/crumbIssuer/api/json";
        Method = 'Get';
        Headers = $header;}
$API_Crumb = Invoke-RestMethod @Params
write-host $API_Crumb
$h.Add('Jenkins-Crumb', $API_Crumb.crumb)
$Params['uri'] = "https://jenkinsservername/$JobName/build?token=$JobToken"
$Params['Method'] = 'Post'
$Params['Headers'] = $header
Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote name could not be resolved: 'https'
At C:\path\to\script.ps1:12 char:14

- $API_Crumb = Invoke-RestMethod @Params1
- ```
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

  Invoke-RestMethod : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  At C:\path\to\script.ps1:19 char:1

  - Invoke-RestMethod @Params2 -WebSession $Session
  - ```
      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], NullReferenceException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
    ```

You contributions will be appreciated

Comment: The `$API_URL` points to `htpps` and not `https`. Also you’re not declaring `API_Port`. You’re also including additional URL in `uri = "http://`

Comment: Are you getting status 200 OK or a 400/500 error?  If you are getting 200 OK than issue is probably the webpage has java scripts running and you are reading results before the java completes giving a null object.  There are a few ways of fixing issue.  Most recommend using a Webbrowser instead of Invoke-RestMethod which waits for Java scripts to complete.  See : https://superuser.com/questions/924194/powershell-how-to-invoke-javascript-on-a-web-page-using-autobrowse-module I have instead when I have this issue is to loop until the element is not null using htmlutilitypack.

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod : The remote name could not be resolved: 'https'

At C:\path\to\script.ps1:12 char:14

+ $API_Crumb = Invoke-RestMethod @Params1

+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: @jdweng Above is the error i keep getting anytime i run the script

Comment: Is error on first or second Invoke-Request?  First request is to get token.  Second request is to Post data.  The second request is using the same header as first.  The headers need to be different because first headers are asking for a token while second request cannot ask for a token.  Instead should be using the token returned in first request.

Comment: Remove the `"https://` from `$Params`… You’re already declaring it in `$API_URL`

Comment: Yes, i noticed that too and hard to remove that part from my code. Now trim down to this error

Comment: @user17095978 Please update the post with all the progress and new errors. Don’t use the comments for this, it just confuses people and does not allow for other members to assist.